# Can't figure out which selectors to use in .each function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some dynamically-generated html code:

```
<div id="slider-7238" class="hps-slide" style="width:250px; height:50px;">
    <div class="hps-sliderText">
        Custom Pizza<br />
        Left: Mushrooms / Green Peppers<br/>Right: Cheese<span class="slide-more" id="slide-more-7238"> MORE... </span>
            <div class="slide-full-desc" id="slide-desc-7238">Left: Mushrooms / Green Peppers<br/>Right: Ultimate Cheese</div>                           
    </div>
</div>

<div id="slider-3471" class="hps-slide" style="width:250px; height:50px;">
    <div class="hps-sliderText">
        Chicken Alfredo<br />
        Grilled chicken breast strips and rotini pasta oven-baked<span class="slide-more" id="slide-more-3471"> MORE... </span>
            <div class="slide-full-desc" id="slide-desc-3471">Grilled chicken breast strips and rotini pasta oven-baked in a creamy Alfredo sauce with a layer of melted cheese. Served with an order of breadsticks.</div>                                    
    </div>
</div>

<div id="slider-7261" class="hps-slide" style="width:250px; height:50px;">
    <div class="hps-sliderText">
        Custom Pizza<br />
        Left: Ham<br/>Right: Cheese
    </div>
</div>
```

There can be any number of these chunks, and the id numbers associated with them are never known. I have a javascript function that takes the `slide-more` spans and turns them into mouseover tooltips, with the contents of the `slide-full-desc` divs as the tooltip content. The function works correctly if I hard-code in the div ids to use, but I can't do that because of the dynamic generation. I'm trying to use it in a .each function, but can't seem to get the selectors correct. I'm not getting any errors; it's just not all working.

Here's the code as it stands:

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
        $('span.slide-more').each(function (i) {
            new QoTooltip($(this), $('slide-full-desc').html(), {'layout':'top'});
        });
    });
```

The params for QoTooltip are the element to mouseover, the element that contains the tooltip content, and some settings (in this case, just layout.)

What I need is to have the function apply a new QoTooltip to each span and pass in the contents of the related slide-full-desc div. They are related by the four-digit number attached to their IDs (i.e. `span id="slide-more-3471"` would need to get the html of the `slide-desc-3471` div.

The mouseover works, so it's at least getting the .each on the spans, but I'm not sure how to get the correct content into the second param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(this).next('.slide-full-desc').html();
```

**Full Code**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
      $('span.slide-more').each(function (i) {
          var $this = $(this);
          new QoTooltip($this, $this.next('.slide-full-desc').html()
                                                             , {'layout':'top'});
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
$('span.slide-more').each(function (i) {
    new QoTooltip($(this), $(this).next('.slide-full-desc').html(), {'layout':'top'});
});
```

Comment: Accepted Sushanth's answer only because I saw it first. Yours works too.